# Weather API for data forcast for next 30 days

Tags: api, weather

Is there any web service/API which can provide weather forecast details for next 30 or more days?

Some API like google,yahoo are giving data for only next 5 days.

Thanks

Comment: No, the [Farmer's Almanac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farmers'_Almanac) doesn't provide an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long-term forecasting is available from AWS (WeatherBug), see http://weather.weatherbug.com/weatherbug-professional/products/forecasting/mcast - they do have an API but I'm not sure if their API includes the long-term data.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody on this planet can give you a weather forecast for 30 days. 5 days is the absolute maximum of what's halfway reliable.

There are long term forecasts based on climate models but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: lol...ok i'll adjust myself according to next 5 days weather data